# systemd service on Linux for edison for Node

Tags: node.js, linux, intel-edison

I've got the following service that I'm trying to run on startup. I've made a service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Denny node server start
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/root
Type=forking
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
User=nobody                                 
Group=nobody                                
RemainAfterExit=true                        
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/root/server.js
KillMode=process          
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
[Install]                 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've dropped this in /etc/systemd/system/ then I run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

then

```
systemctl start denny
```

Nothing. No server is started up. Ok, I check on it:

```
root@denny:~# systemctl status denny
```

I get back:

```
● denny.service - Denny node server start
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/denny.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-02-13 17:13:21 UTC; 29min ago
 Main PID: 225 (code=exited, status=8)
   CGroup: /system.slice/denny.service

Feb 13 17:41:40 denny systemd[1]: Started Denny node server start.
```

I may be mis-remembering but seems to be *exactly* what I did on Debian and it worked fine, i.e. it kept the service running and acting as it should. Am I missing something in this .service file that would tell the default Linux for edison to keep this running?

Comment: I'm not familiar with node, though I've got a few ideas. First, does node actually exit normally? Otherwise you should remove the RemainAfterExit line. If node normally forks, how do systemd get hold of the PID of the new process? Secondly, systemctl indicates that node exited with return code 8, which ought to indicate an error. Check those two things and you should probably be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer only works with the Node.js answer but a solution (and the one I went with) was to place my node application in /node_app_slot in the filesystem with the following package.json also in the /node_app_slot:

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

This allows the XDK daemon to pick up and run the Node app on boot. Fairly painless and simple but not super well documented.